# Python HTTP Response Becoming Download Document

Tags: python, sockets, http

I have a server in python using sockets that handle http requests.

One of my pages is a form that just submits a first and last name. The response should just be an "eco". Instead the response becomes a downloadable file.

[image: my form]

Expected result:

[image: expected]

What happens:

[image]

Python response:

b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nDate: Tue, 02 Jun 2020 13:04:46 \nContent-Type: application/json/\nContent-Length: 40\r\n\r\n{"firstname": "Hi", "lastname": "Stack"}'

How can I show the contents of the "form" file instead of it becoming a downloadable file?

Comment: It looks as if you've set the content-type of your reponse to `application/json/` (note the trailing slash) when you probably meant `application/json`.

Comment: It partially solved it, thanks for noticing it!